# Is there a way to execute a native binary from a pipe?

Tags: shell, executable, stdout

```
echo 'main(){}' | gcc -xc - -o /dev/stdout | ???
```

Is there a way to run the output binary on a unix-like system?

**EDIT:** I needed it to run the output of g++ in a sandboxed environment where I can't write *any* file (nothing malicious, I promise).

Comment: I believe that basic security mechanisms must prevent this. But if your intension is to run C code on-the-fly, just use `csh`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  The [exec(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html) system call always requires a filename or absolute path (the filename is always a `char*`).  [`posix_spawn`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/posix_spawn.html) also has similar requirements for a filename.

The closest you could do is pipe the output into a named pipe and try executing from the pipe.  That may work, although the shell may refuse to execute any file that does not have the `--x--x--x` bits set.  Create the pipe with [`mkfifo(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo) and see if you can get it to work.

Another approach would be to write something that reads standard input, writes a file out to a temporay area, sets the --x bits on it, forks and execs then deletes the file.  The inode and contents will remain until the program finishes executing but it won't be accessible through the file system.  When the process terminates the inode will be released and storage will be returned to the free list.

**EDIT:** As Mat points out, the first approach won't work as the loader will attempt to demand-page in the executable, which will generate random seek traffic on the file, and this isn't possible on a pipe.  This leaves some sort of approach like the second.

Comment: I'd be really surprised if the pipe trick worked - you can't do random seeks on a pipe, and can't mmap them - I'm pretty sure that will annoy the runtime loader/linker :) Your second suggestion seems good though, can't come up with anything without a temporary file.

Comment: @Mat - I think you're right. Demand paging in the executable would cause random access traffic which won't work on the pipe. Ironically it might have actually worked on SVR2.0 (the last version that didn't use demand paging) - Just to show my age I actually used to have an AT&T 3B2/400 once with SVR2.0 as the O/S.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I'm pretty sure exe packers like UPX can do the decompression _and_ execution on read-only media. Modify whatever stub they tack on to packed executables to read from a pipe rather than decompress, and ... might work.

Comment: @Mat packers already have an image loaded they don't start a new process. To do the similar I need to have one of processes to make an arbitrary jump into input data (which would be considered a security vulnerability).

Comment: @Alex B: You are specifically asking how to make an arbitrary jump into input data. Why would you complain when it's suggested that you do exactly that? Is the purpose of the sandbox specifically to prevent what you're trying to do?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Where was I complaining? Just pointing out that (1) packers can't read from a pipe and (2) *general-purpose* utilities like `echo`, `cat` won't do the jump. Anyway, the sandbox (ideone.com) already allows running g++ and its output, so you are already running pretty much arbitrary code, I just needed to run g++ with additional compiler flags.

Comment: @Alex B: You say, "which would be considered a security vulnerability". Maybe I misunderstood what you meant by that. Of course it's a security vulnerability, but it's specifically what you're trying to do. You're going to have to use subversion, like starting one process, suspending it, using another process to modify its memory image, and then resuming it.

Answer (score 6):

You could try [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/), which will compile and execute a program in one step, without writing any intermediate files. It's not gcc, which may be a problem for you, but it is spectacularly fast, so it may even bet better than gcc for your purposes.

Answer (score 6):

A solution using memfd syscall: https://github.com/abbat/elfexec

It creates a named file descriptor in memory which could be used in `exec`. A pseudo-code:

```
#include <linux/memfd.h>
...
int memfd = syscall(SYS_memfd_create, "someName", 0);
...
write(memfd,... elf-content...);
...
fexecve(memfd, argv, environ);
```

Comment: You don't need the `memfd.h` header unless you want to use `MFD_CLOEXEC` (which will break `#! /bin/sh` scripts because of bugs in linux' `fexecve()`). That's not too complicated, you can include a 20-line working sample in your answer (eg. [this git gist](https://gist.github.com/0xef967c36/4b7f68ec09cd461f0dfba7c909e089b2) -- though that's not a drop-in replacement for your `elfexec`, since that will also allow you to specify `argv[0]`, and will run a binary *only from a pipe* (UUoC mandated ;-))

Comment: So I don't get how this expected to work at all. gcc will write `.o` files to /tmp and die if it can't.

Answer (score 2):

This will automatically run the compilation of your code, but creates a file (temparaily) on the filesystem in order to do it.

```
echo 'main(){}' | gcc -xc -o /tmp/a.out && chmod u+x /tmp/a.out && /tmp/a.out && rm -f /tmp/a.out
```

(I'm currently testing this now, but I'm pretty sure this, or something close to it will work for you)

EDIT: If the goal of your piping is to cut physical disks out of the equation for speed, consider creating a [ram disk](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/) to hold the intermediate file.

Comment: This will work of course, but it misses the main point of the question - to execute a binary code that is never written to disk.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz My hope was the it would be useful if the goal was to easily run a snippit of code on the fly without dealing with the required physical file.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But for that, one could simply use `csh`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like [@TheQUUX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/18641/thequux) suggested, I haven't tested it my self but you might want to try out [`cling`](https://root.cern.ch/cling) - "the interactive C++ interpreter, built on top of LLVM and Clang libraries.".

Find more info here: https://cdn.rawgit.com/root-project/cling/master/www/index.html

Answer (score 0):

From @kan [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492559/257838) and a perl implementation also done [in this blog](https://magisterquis.github.io/2018/03/31/in-memory-only-elf-execution.html). This prints "Hello from C".

Requires: perl, base64, gunzip

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# From: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492559/257838
# And: https://magisterquis.github.io/2018/03/31/in-memory-only-elf-execution.html


execute_elf_string(){
  local bin_encoded=$1
  perl -e '
    require qw/syscall.ph/;

    # Create memfd
    my $name = "";
    my $fd = syscall(SYS_memfd_create(), $fn, 0);
    if (-1 == $fd) { die "memfd_create: $!"; }

    # Copy binary
    open(my $fh, ">&=".$fd) or die "open: $!";
    my $bin = `echo "'"$bin_encoded"'" | base64 -d | gunzip`;
    print $fh $bin;

    # Execute
    exec {"/proc/$$/fd/$fd"} "memfd";
  '
}

execute_elf_string "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"
```

To encode the binary to string, run

```bash
gzip -f < hi.so | base64
```

Answer (score 0):

In any case, `gcc` creates many temporary files when compiling C files into executables:

```
$ echo 'int main(){}' | strace -fe /open -o >(grep CREAT) gcc -xc -
96706 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/ccxiPEgx.s", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
96707 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/ccxiPEgx.s", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 0
96706 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/ccIBSUD4.o", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
96711 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/ccIBSUD4.o", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
96706 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/cciAP0FV.res", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
96712 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/ccfZa2PH.cdtor.c", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
96712 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/cc4LkCnx.cdtor.o", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
96713 openat(AT_FDCWD, "a.out", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
```

So you might as well create another one for the final executable.

If on Linux, it could be a pre-deleted one. For instance, with shells that still implement here-documents or here-strings as deleted temporary files such as zsh:

```
$ echo 'int main(){puts("Hello World");}' | { gcc -o /dev/fd/3 -x c  - && /dev/fd/3; } 3<<< ''
<stdin>: In function ‘main’:
<stdin>:1:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘puts’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
<stdin>:1:1: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘puts’
Hello World
```