# Why can't I chown a pipe?

Tags: pipe, chown

From a discussion on [useless use of cat](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511827/3562).

I decided to see if It was possible to avoid some of the troubles by changing the owner of the pipe. So I did:

```
# cat | cat &
[1] 16500
# cd /proc/16500/fd
# ls -l
lr-x------ root root 0 -> pipe:[931613]
lrwx------ root root 1 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ root root 2 -> /dev/tty1
# chown --dereference daemon 0
# ls -l
lr-x------ root root 0 -> pipe:[931613]
lrwx------ root root 1 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ root root 2 -> /dev/tty1
```

I also tried `chown` and `chown -L`. No go. I'm convinced this is simply impossible, but why? They clearly have inodes. That 931613 is the inode number.

In the case I am actually interested in, the process on the right would be running at lower privileges and I'd kind of like it to own its own handles so that it can re-open them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I goofed up my `ls` command.

```
# ls -lL
lr-x------ daemon root 0 -> pipe:[931613]
lrwx------ root   root 1 -> /dev/tty1
lrwx------ root   root 2 -> /dev/tty1
```

This was not a typo. This was an error in logic that happens to be fixed with one character. You see, I *know* these nodes aren't really symbolic links because opening them yields the correct file even if it was opened in a chroot jail, which yields an incorrect path in the `ls -l` output. Somehow I thought the kernel system call returned more attributes of the underlying inode than it actually does.