# Why doesn't mkfifo with a mode of 1755 grant read permissions and sticky bit to the user?

Tags: permissions, c, mkfifo

I'm creating a server and client  situation where i want to create a pipe so they can communicate.

I created the pipe in the server code with 
`mkfifo("fifo",1755);`:

- 1 for only user that created and root to be able to delete it or rename it,
- 7 for give read, write and exec to user, and
- 5 for both group and other to only give them read and exec.

The problem is that later in the server code I open  the fifo to read from it `open("fifo",O_RDONLY);` but when i execute it, it shows me an perror that denies me acess to the fifo.

I went to see the permissions of the pipe fifo and it says 
`p-wx--s--t` so:

- `p` stands for pipe,
- `-` means the user has no read. I don't know how when I gave it with the 7,
- `s` group executes has user. I don't how if i gave 1 so supposedly it should give to user and others the ability to only read and execute and others have t that was expected.

Do I have a misunderstanding of the permissions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot simply exec a binary from a pipe: [Is there a way to execute a native binary from a pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22253/is-there-a-way-to-execute-a-native-binary-from-a-pipe). Also I don't think the sticky bit on executables is worth anything on modern systems.

> I created the pipe in the server code with `mkfifo("fifo",1755);`
>
> I went to see the permissions of the pipe fifo and it says `p-wx--s--t` so:

Your error is to have written the `1755` permission without the leading `0`, which means that `1755` has been treated as a decimal instead of octal (`1755 & ~022 = 03311 = p-wx--s--t`; where `022` is your umask)

Comment: So  a better solution would be create a dir and chmod 1755 the dir then create the pipe in that dir with ```  mkfifo ("fifo",755); ``` ?

Comment: The sticky bit has different semantics for files and directories: for directories it prevents users from removing or renaming files they don't own; for regular files it doesn't mean much nowadays. Read the chmod(2) manpage for all the details. Also, `mkfifo("fifo", 0755)` with the leading `0` ;-).

Comment: i tried mkfifo("fifo",0777); but i only got `prwxr-xr-x`but if i do chmod 0777 fifo after i created fifo i get  `prwxrwxrwx`any idea why it doesnt work when i create it

Comment: Because of the umask -- the umask which is 022 will mask out the write permissions from group (020) and other (002) anytime a file is created with open(2), mkfifo(2), etc. Read the umask(2) manpage. The umask doesn't affect the chmod syscall or command.